# Alterar valor da variável php através de media queries

Tags: php, css

Preciso alterar o valor da variável de uma função conforme a resolução do ecrã(ao reduzir o ecrã o valor terá que ser imediatamente actualizado). Será possível alterar esse valor através de CSS media queries?

Ou seja, algo deste tipo com css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1065px) {
    $variavel = 3;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {
    $variavel = 2;
}
```

Para recuperar o valor no php:

`catalogo($variavel)`;

Existe alguma forma de fazer isto?

Obrigado

Comment: Não faz muito sentido essa pegunta. Não existe "variável PHP" quando o cliente está acessando a página. Só existe PHP enquanto o servidor monta o conteúdo. Depois é que vai para o browser, onde as _queries_ serão processadas. No máximo, o que você pode fazer é enviar a largura da tela via JS ou coisa do tipo para outro PHP armazenar.

Comment: Cara não tem como fazer desse jeito não... PHP e CSS não casam dessa forma que você está imaginando. O ideal seria pegar o tamanho da tela através de Javascript e ai passar para o PHP, isso é possível.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas, vou pensar noutra forma de fazer o que preciso. Obrigado também pelas sugestões.

Comment: @TiagoPereira qual a finalidade desse código. Diga-nos o que você pretende fazer. Talvez possamos apontar um caminho.

Comment: Pô, usa um less ou um sass :D

Answer (score 2):

PHP é uma linguagem Server Side e CSS é uma linguagem Client Side..

Não existe uma comunicação directa entre elas. No entanto, através de AJAX é possível realizar alguma comunicação entre as duas.

Aconselho-te a ler sobre AJAX, aqui tens um bom link para começar http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp

No entanto, indica-nos o que pretendes mesmo fazer para que possamos indicar-te um melhor caminho, penso que o AJAX será demasiado complexo para o que precisas..